# Maven multiple module conflict

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-plugin, maven-3, maven-release-plugin

```
<module>APP_1</module>
<module>web_1</module>
<module>service_1</module>
<module>schema_1</module>

<module>APP_2</module>
<module>web_2</module>
<module>service_2</module>
<<module>schema_2</module>
```

I have project structure like this but in some project if i want to build service_1 i need service_2 and for building service_2 i need service_1 vice versa.

So how should i resolved this conflict with maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't resolve this conflict with Maven or with any other build tool.  It's not a build tool issue, it is an architectural flaw and can only be addressed through [refactoring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring).

Two options come immediately to mind:

1) Create a new module called "service_common" that contains the stuff that both service_1 need and service_2 need.  The make service_common a dependency of both of those modules.

2) Move the stuff that service_1 needs from service_2 into service_1.  Then service_1 depends on nothing and service_2 depends on service_1.

There are many ways to solve this, but circular inter-module dependencies are a big time NO-NO regardless of language or build tool.